# Readobject() function flags an json injection fortify issue

Tags: json, serialization, json.net, deserialization, fortify

[image: Fortify issue]

This is my Serialization Helper class. I got  error: Deserialize() writes 
unvalidated input into JSON. This call could allow an attacker to inject arbitary elements or attributes into the JSON entity.

it's coming from ReadObject(steam).

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a screenshot. And what kind of error do you get? Compiler error or warning, or some code analyzer error?

Comment: I am not getting any compilation error. It's fortify issue. please check http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/dotnet/json_injection.html

Comment: Check the reported stack trace.  This function on its face is vulnerable to injection since you do no verification of the input and the function is public.